# xcode file and directory issue

Tags: xcode, xcode4

I have a project.  I copied it and pasted it with another name and changed the images.

In Xcode I also changed the project name, but the actual folder name is still same.

I have copied in a new icon image but it's still showing the old project icon.

Now I tried to change the actual folder name. Xcode is giving me an error from clang: "file or directory not found".

Can anyone tell me how to fix both of these problems?

Comment: What happened to StackOverflow as a place where proper grammar was used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove (de-reference) the project icon, then re-add it. Do a Build-Clean, then a Build-All.

If that doesn't fix it, then you have a hard-coded path in your `.plist` - edit that to get rid of the hard path.

Comment: i did what u said but still same problem and can u also help me regarding Xcode giving error if i tries to change actual folder name

Comment: If you change the folder containing an Xcode project, you need to close all projects, then File/Open in Xcode, find your moved project, and open it.